# Lowering the freezing point of a lipid by adding another lipid

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry, phase, food-chemistry

I'm trying to stop bacon grease from congealing in the fridge by adding another lipid with a lower freeze point to it, but I'm not sure how much to add, as I'd like to keep the ratio as bacon-grease heavy as possible.

Of the oils I have available, corn oil has the lowest freeze point at -11C (http://www.veganbaking.net/articles/tools/fat-and-oil-melt-point-temperatures), and bacon grease has a freezing point of 26C (https://www.doesitgobad.com/does-bacon-grease-go-bad/). I need to bring the freezing point down to 5C or lower.

Can I calculate the melting point of the mixture simply by finding the average melting temp between the two according to their ratios? So for corn oil:

```
T = (26b + -11c) / (b + c)
Where T=Freezing temp. of resulting mixture, b=# parts bacon grease, and c=# parts corn oil
```

If not, how should I calculate the ratio of corn oil to bacon grease to bring the freezing point to 5C? Can I calculate it the same way if I use cottonseed oil (-48C freezing point) instead of corn oil?

Comment: I doubt that will work, but chemistry is an experimental science so try it with a small quantity of bacon grease and oil. -- I'd guess that you'll get something that is part solid and part liquid.

Comment: I doubt it would be the average. That kind of stuff happens in fairy tales alone.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression

Comment: From observing virgin olive oil, there is not one single melting point. Which makes sense if there is any variation in chain length. So you may get a broader range of melting, but that isn't what you seem to be looking for.